# Configure key binding behavior in Ruby's pry

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ruby

The key bindings in ruby's "pry" editor started behaving differently than they do in "irb", and I want to know how to change the behavior (which feels it should be configurable).

Specifically, "Alt-B" and "Alt-F" would jump back or forward in the line I typed and stop at "word boundaries". The difference is that "pry" and "irb" now have different ideas what a "word boundary" is.

E.g., if I type the following text

```
a.b.c.d
```

and at the end of the line I start hitting "Alt-B", I would expect the cursor to go back to `d`, then to `c`, then to `b`. This is what happens in `irb`, but in `pry` it goes all the way back to the `a`.

Similar inconsistency if I type

```
a,b,c,d
```

In this case pressing "Ctrl-W" should delete the whole string, but this only works in `irb`. In `pry` it would only delete the `d`, then `c,`, then `b,`, and finally the `a`.

Another key binding that changed behavior seems to be `Control-U` and `Control-K`. These used to delete all characters to the beginning of the line, or the end of the line respectively, but in `pry` `control-u` now deletes the whole line.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround was to install the `rb-readline` in my project. My bindings work as expected now.

I noticed that the ruby readline gem does not seem to link against the system libreadline library, and it does not have any references to `INPUTRC` or `inputrc` in it.

Then I looked at the [readline libraries suggested by pry](https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/d5a1f1c9847bb5272f2f8b2c2a0c174c83064b66/lib/pry/config.rb#L296) and realized that installing `rb-readline` solves my problem.

> Sorry, you can't use Pry without Readline or a compatible library.
>
> Possible solutions:
>
> - Rebuild Ruby with Readline support using `--with-readline`
> - Use the rb-readline gem, which is a pure-Ruby port of Readline
> - Use the pry-coolline gem, a pure-ruby alternative to Readline